# Set own directory for saving files by windows service

Tags: windows, service, path, save

is it possible set custom save path for saving files created by my windows service something like this: D:/my_service_save_path/ ? It always saves files in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ for now.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you talking about the _working directory_ ? As long as you don't rely on UNC or network drives your service has no permissions for specifying an absolute path should do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use \ instead of / if u're in a Windows OS

Comment: I tried both...same results, files ended in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in absolutely different place. Actually it is stupid, because I use external library for this a forgot update .dll :/

Thank you guys.